# My sqlite database is not able to persist anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I have a Rails Api with models, controllers, and serializers. The database is set up, and I have made several migrations, all of which have resulted in corresponding changes to the schema. However, nothing is being persisted to the database, either in the rails console or from the seed data. For instance, when I try to run User.create in the console, I see this message appear:

```
2.3.3 :003 > User.create
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Similarly, I have this data in my seeds file:

```
users = User.create([{ email: 'adam@adam.com' }, { email: 'ryan@ryan.com' 
 }])
BankAccount.create(name: 'Adams Chase Checking Account', user_id: users.first)
```

When I run rake db:seed and attempt to call User.all or BankAccount.all in the rails console, I am given an empty array in both cases. I have heard of errors like this being caused by unmet validations on the models, but my models do not have any validations. I am at a loss as to what could be causing this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated! Also, for what it's worth, this project uses Rails 5.1.4, and I have only used 4.x.x previously. Here is the User model (using devise):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable 
has_many :bank_accounts 
has_many :credit_cards
has_many :investments 
has_many :loans 
has_many :assets 
has_many :recurring_payments, through: :bank_accounts
has_many :recurring_payments, through: :credit_cards
has_many :recurring_payments, through: :investments
has_many :recurring_payments, through: :loans
end
```

And here is the bank account model:

```
class BankAccount < ApplicationRecord 
belongs_to :user 
has_many :recurring_payments 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :recurring_payments
end
```

Here is the full schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180205231948) do

create_table "assets", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "name"
t.integer "value"
t.integer "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "bank_accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "name"
t.integer "balance"
t.integer "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "credit_cards", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "provider"
t.integer "balance"
t.integer "interest_rate"
t.integer "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "investments", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "name"
t.integer "value"
t.integer "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "loans", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "user_id"
t.integer "interest_rate"
t.integer "remaining_balance"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "recurring_payments", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "source"
t.boolean "status"
t.date "pay_date"
t.integer "pay_amount"
t.integer "duration"
t.integer "bank_account_id"
t.integer "credit_card_id"
t.integer "loan_id"
t.integer "investment_id"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "email", default: "", null: false
t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
t.string "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: 
"index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is this.

```
users = User.create([{ email: 'adam@adam.com' }, { email: 'ryan@ryan.com' }])
```

Devise validates the default password before saving (6 characters minimum). Try running this command in console and see if it throws any errors?

```
user = User.create(email: 'adam@adam.com')
user.errors
```

Comment: Ahh ok youre right, it says password cant be blank. However, this doesnt explain the error in creating bank accounts, or any of the other models (I dont think)?

Comment: BankAccount has a reference to the user, I guess, that might be the problem.

Comment: Great. Don't forget to upvote or mark this as an answer. :)